# Trying to use list function to limit input in while loop in my guessing game

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def random():
x_val = randint(1,100)
limit = []
limit2 = len(limit)
while True:
    try:
        roll = int(raw_input("Please pick a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print "Please input numbers only"
        continue
    if limit2 <= 5:
        if roll > 100 or roll < 1:
            print "Exceed Limited Guess"
            continue
        elif roll < x_val:
            limit.append(1)
            sleep(1)
            print "Your guess is lower!"
            continue
        elif roll > x_val:
            limit.append(1)
            sleep(1)
            print "Your guess is higher!"
            continue
        elif roll == x_val:
            print limit2
            return "You guessed correct! You win!"
            break
        else:
            print "Incorrect Input"
            continue
    elif limit2 > 5:
        return "You guessed over 5 times. You lose, sucker..."
        break
    elif limit2 == 4:
        print "Last guess!"
        continue    
print "Welcome to my world! You will have to pick a correct number from 1 to 100!    
If you can do it within 5 times you win! Otherwise you suck!"
while True:
    try:
        start = raw_input("Start Rolling? Yes or No: ").lower()
    except ValueError:
        print "Answer Yes or no"
        continue
    if start == "y" or start == "yes" or start == "ye":
        user2 = random()
        print user2
    elif start == "n" or start == "no" or start == "noo":
        print "Ready when you are"
        continue
    else:
        print "Answer Yes or No"
        continue
```

Hi, I am working on a guessing game from 1-100 that I built from ground up by myself and doing research, my original code is not even close to this. 
  Now, I am stuck on the last part I cannot use the list to limit the input in while loop. I want to stop the game after 5 guesses. However every time it always keep going and once it win it printed out "0" for limit2 variable.

Thank you

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Since `random` is the name of a heavily used module (one that you are in fact using) also calling a function `random` is not a good name choice.

Comment: I definitely agree with John Coleman suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I will definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: Just saw the mistake I got it fix! Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you never update the "counter" of the attempted tries made by the user. You initialize it at the beginning (through `limit2 = len(limit)`), but you never update that value, therefore causing an endless loop.

You simply need to perform the check on *len(limit)* instead of on *limit2*.

Working solution can be found below. I took the liberty of commenting *limit2* (as it is not needed anymore), improving the indentation, adding two `import`s, replacing `sleep` with `time.sleep`, and fixing the number of checks to perform (if you are aiming at 5 maximum tries, `len(limit)` needs to be less than 5).

```
from random import randint
import time

def random():
    x_val = randint(1,100)
    limit = []
    # limit2 = len(limit)
    while True:
        try:
            roll = int(raw_input("Please pick a number: "))
        except ValueError:
            print "Please input numbers only"
            continue
        if len(limit) < 5:
            if roll > 100 or roll < 1:
                print "Exceed Limited Guess"
                continue
            elif roll < x_val:
                limit.append(1)
                time.sleep(1)
                print "Your guess is lower!"
                continue
            elif roll > x_val:
                limit.append(1)
                time.sleep(1)
                print "Your guess is higher!"
                continue
            elif roll == x_val:
                print len(limit)
                return "You guessed correct! You win!"
                break
            else:
                print "Incorrect Input"
                continue
        elif len(limit) >= 5:
            return "You guessed over 5 times. You lose, sucker..."
            break
    print "Welcome to my world! You will have to pick a correct number from 1 to 100! If you can do it within 5 times you win! Otherwise you suck!"

while True:
    try:
        start = raw_input("Start Rolling? Yes or No: ").lower()
    except ValueError:
        print "Answer Yes or no"
        continue
    if start == "y" or start == "yes" or start == "ye":
        user2 = random()
        print user2
    elif start == "n" or start == "no" or start == "noo":
        print "Ready when you are"
        continue
    else:
        print "Answer Yes or No"
        continue
```

Worthy of note is that -- among several other things that should be fixed in your code -- you should avoid calling a function *random*, since it is already a name used by [a very common module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html).

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I am nearly there I tried according to your advice, somehow it takes me 6 tries before it says I lose. 
For the time.sleep(1) I dont know if it because i'm using python 2.7 or sublime it only works if i use sleep(1).

Comment: If you kept `if len(limit)<=5` then it will check for an additional try before saying that you lose (it will check the value for 6 times, and at the 7th time it will simply say that you lose). You need to set it to `if len(limit)<5` (remember to also edit the final `elif` -- or, even better, just use an `else`)

Comment: That is definitely an important info I will remember! Thank you again got it to work perfectly! this is really fun.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you found that my suggestion answered your question, please upvote and accept it, thanks :)